# Reducing transformer lamination thickness

Tags: voltage, current, transformer, power-electronics, electromagnetism

What will happen if you reduced the core thickness of a 200 kVA transformer  lamination. I am trying to reduce the lamination of a 200 kVA transformer, so that my coil can go in freely but I am wondering if it will have any effect on the transformer.

Comment: It will reduce the Vs, the volts.seconds core product. At best that will increase the Bfield swing in the core and increase core losses, at worst it will saturate the core, draw huge current, not quite trip your breakers and overheat the transformer. It depends what fraction you remove, and how conservatively designed the transformer was in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to increase the window area so you can fit more windings in the transformer.  You want to do this by removing some of the laminations?

If so, with all else the same you are going to increase the flux swing, increase the core losses, and reduce the thermal mass.  If the transformer was designed for 200kva and you run the modified transformer at the same power, best case it will run hotter with less margin.

Worse case it will trip its thermal protection and shut down.

Worst case it has no thermal protection and fails spectacularly.

However it sounds like you are changing the windings as well.  Without knowing exactly what you are changing and how, and what the intended use and power requirement is it's impossible to say what the effect would be.

Comment: Thanks John☺. the lamination it self was exposed to rain and sunlight so it kind of expand that the LT coil is unable to fit in. So am thinking of reducing the lamination but I don't know the effects it will hav on the transformer.